# kubectl versions Error: exec plugin is configured to use API version client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1

Tags: authentication, plugins, kubectl, amazon-eks

I was setting up my new Mac for my eks environment.
After the installation of kubectl, aws-iam-authenticator and the kubeconfig file placement in default location. I ran the command kubectl command and got this error mentioned below in command block.

My cluster uses v1alpha1 client auth api version so basically i wanted to use the same one in my Mac as well.

I tried with latest version (1.23.0) of kubectl as well, still the same error. Whereas When i tried to do with aws-iam-authenticator (version 0.5.5) I was not able to download lower version.

Can someone help me to resolve it?

```
% kubectl version          
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20", GitVersion:"v1.20.0", GitCommit:"af46c47ce925f4c4ad5cc8d1fca46c7b77d13b38", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-12-08T17:59:43Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Unable to connect to the server: getting credentials: exec plugin is configured to use API version client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1, plugin returned version client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1
```

Thanks and Regards,
Saravana

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error: exec plugin: invalid apiVersion "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1" CircleCI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72126048/error-exec-plugin-invalid-apiversion-client-authentication-k8s-io-v1alpha1-c)

Comment: downgrading kubectl version to `1.22` fix the issue for my mate

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I have the same problem

You're using `aws-iam-authenticator` `0.5.5`, AWS changed the way it behaves in `0.5.4` to require `v1beta1`.

It depends on your configuration, but you can try to change the K8s context you're using to `v1beta1`
by checking your kubeconfig file (usually in `~/.kube/config`) from `client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1` to `client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1`

Otherwise switch back to `aws-iam-authenticator` `0.5.3` - you might need to build it from source if you're using the M1 architecture as there's no `darwin-arm64` binary built for it

Comment: For some additional info, the change is described here:
https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-iam-authenticator/pull/386
I was able to resolve the issue in my case by updating my kubeconfig and replacing
`client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1` with `client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1`

Comment: Changing the `kubeconfig` did the trick for me as well.  In the GitHub issue provided by @pgier there is a slick one-liner to make the change for you: `sed -i .bak -e 's/v1alpha1/v1beta1/' ~/.kube/config`

Comment: I had the same issue and the @pgier answer helped. Thanks

Answer (score 17):

This worked for me using M1 chip

```
sed -i .bak -e 's/v1alpha1/v1beta1/' ~/.kube/config
```

Comment: Thank you. It works on non-M1 chips also. However this may uncover a new issue with recent versions of kubectl and aws CLI : https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/issues/1210

Answer (score 10):

I fixed the issue with command below

```
aws eks update-kubeconfig --name mycluster
```

Comment: Which version of the AWS CLI are you using?

Comment: I forgot what version was used, it is changed quickly.

Comment: BTW, I have impression the AWS CLI should be kept updated.

Answer (score 6):

Also make sure the AWS CLI version is up-to-date. Otherwise, AWS IAM Authenticator might not work with v1beta1:

```
curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"
unzip awscliv2.zip
sudo ./aws/install --update
```

as shown in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-install.html

Comment: I had this too. I just created an EC2 VM with Amazon Linux and it gave me this ancient version of aws cli `aws-cli/1.18.147`. Trying to do an upgrade didn't help either because no newer version was available, so I did the commands in the solution to get the latest v2 aws cli. Then `aws eks update-kubeconfig --name mycluster` to regenerate the config.

Comment: Worth mentioning that the commands in this answer are the official commands from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-install.html

Comment: @TomSaleeba v1 is not "ancient". It still gets regular updates; 1.32.33 was released [yesterday](https://pypi.org/project/awscli/1.32.33/). The reason you couldn't upgrade it to v2 however, is AWS being "too big to be competent", I mean, [they intentionally don't publish v2 to PyPI](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/4947). Because lunatic reasons, check yourself. Among many many many other things, this breaks installation of awscli v2 in... AWS Lambda python runtime. How ironic, because it installs with `pip`. I personally **boycott awscli v2** and am consciously staying on v1.

Answer (score 5):

I also solved this by updating the `apiVersion` value in my kube config file (`~/.kube/config`).

`client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1` to `client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1`

Answer (score 2):

Please change the `authentication apiVersion` from `v1alpha1` to `v1beta1`.

**Old**

```
apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1
```

**New**

```
apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1
```

Answer (score 1):

Downgrading/Upgrading kubectl version worked for me.

You must use a kubectl version that is within one minor version difference of your cluster. For example, a v1.27 client can communicate with v1.26, v1.27, and v1.28 control planes. Using the latest compatible version of kubectl helps avoid unforeseen issues

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR It might not seem to make sense, but upgrading the AWS CLI as mentioned here is probably the solution you are seeking.   Then re-run 'aws update-kubeconfig' to properly fix your .kube/config file.

I had this issue in a terraform project with an AWS backend.  I first tried replacing v1alpha1 with v1beta1, but that resulted in a different error running 'terraform apply':

> Error: Post "https://XXXX.gr7.us-west-1.eks.amazonaws.com/api/v1/namespaces/default/secrets": getting credentials: decoding stdout: no kind "ExecCredential" is registered for version "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1" in scheme "pkg/runtime/scheme.go:100"

Another reference that suggested my kubectl might be out of date.   I'm on OSX and /usr/local/bin/kubectl is symbolically linked to a path inside my Docker Destop app.   Indeed Docker Desktop was v4.6.1 and kubectl was version 1.22.   After update to Docker Desktop 4.20.1, 'kubectl version' itself resulted in:

> error: exec plugin: invalid apiVersion "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1"

After following examples trying to install a separate/downgraded kubectl, I noticed several people said that the AWS CLI needed to be upgraded.   This didn't make sense to me, but after the upgrade to version 2.12.1, I see now that 'aws upgrade-kubeconfig' command fixes the ~/.kube/config file (and perhaps other state) properly, including the v1beta1 change.

In my environment, the command which made that fix is:

> aws eks --region $(terraform output -raw region) update-kubeconfig --name $(terraform output -raw cluster_name) --profile ssa

Comment: Also, I just learned that by editing the original ~/.kube/config by hand, I left behind some state that prevented 'terraform apply' from succeeding later.   I had to delete the config file and re-generate with the aws update-kubeconfig command.  'terraform apply' was failing trying to contact a previous instance DNS name

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful to fix this issue for those who were using GitHub actions.
For my situation I was using `kodermax/kubectl-aws-eks`  with GitHub actions.

I added the `KUBECTL_VERSION` and `IAM_VERSION` environment variables for each steps using `kodermax/kubectl-aws-eks` to keep them in fixed versions.

```
  - name: deploy to cluster
    uses: kodermax/kubectl-aws-eks@master
    env:
      KUBE_CONFIG_DATA: ${{ secrets.KUBE_CONFIG_DATA_STAGING }}
      ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
      ECR_REPOSITORY: my-app
      IMAGE_TAG: ${{ github.sha }
      KUBECTL_VERSION: "v1.23.6"
      IAM_VERSION: "0.5.3"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using kubectl 1.21.9 fixed it for me, with asdf:

```bash
asdf plugin-add kubectl https://github.com/asdf-community/asdf-kubectl.git
asdf install kubectl 1.21.9
```

And I would recommend having a `.tools-versions` file with:

```bash
kubectl 1.21.9
```

This question is a duplicate of [error: exec plugin: invalid apiVersion "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1" CircleCI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72126048/error-exec-plugin-invalid-apiversion-client-authentication-k8s-io-v1alpha1-c)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this can happen if the Kube cache is corrupted (which happened in my case).

Deleting and recreating the below folder worked for me.

```
sudo rm -rf $HOME/.kube && mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
```

Answer (score 0):

if anyone is having this issue in 2023 with macs running Sonoma, chances are you have an issue with an old aws v1 client and v1 artifacts that are lingering even with an enabled aws v2 client. You apparently can't upgrade to a v2 client while having the old v1 client installed.

This link (and its sublinks) talks about how to remove the old v1 aws client completely and replace it with a v2 awscli:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-install.html

I did that, deleted all the existing AWS setting and authorizations in the ~/.aws dir.

Then I

- configured the auth for the AWS via `aws configure`
- reran the `aws eks --region {myregion} update-kubeconfig --name {mykubename} --role-arn {myrolearn}` command for each cluster

that all seemed to work for me and remove the mysterious v1alpha1 issue that remained after trying the other solutions

Answer (score 0):

This issue is heavily versioning-dependent (obviously... I hope).

So pay close attention to what versions of what you've got.

- kubectl v1.24.0 has dropped support for `client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1`, but understands `v1beta1` instead. Yet later versions "stabilize" the API as `client.authentication.k8s.io/v1`.
- Your version of `awscli` is important; see [aws/aws-cli#6916](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/6916).
  *The latest* does not necessarily mean *the best*.
- The version of k8s in your EKS cluster is also important.
  This will determine which of the `v1alpha1`, `v1beta1`, `v1` the server will offer. Your client (kubectl) must be of version capable to understand the API version of your EKS cluster.

It's hard to give generic advice beyond that — because the ways how different versions of these pieces fit together, explode combinatorially.